# The file path to be opened is provided, how to get a handle to the new window?

Tags: c#, winapi, windows-shell

I want to implement a shell context menu **"Open to Left/Right"** that user can open a file with the new window being re-positioned to occupy the left/right half of the screen. Basically I just call `Process.Start(fileName)`, and get the process's `MainWindowHandle`, and pass the handle to `SetWindowPos` to set the window's position.

But some applications (like Word) are running as singleton instance, so `Process.Start("new.docx")` just pass the file name to the running instance, and returns `null`, so I can't get the window handle to do the repositioning.

Is there a workaround for this?

`Any approach (preferred written in C#) is welcome.`

PS. I know I can just use `EnumWindows` to list all the top-level windows and let user to select which one he likes to reposition. But that is another use scenario. I want to implement the function in shell context menu.

Comment: There is no simple fix for this, you cannot find out that it is a single instance app and what kind of internal negotiation it performs.  Using MainWindowHandle is in general a lossy approach, you'll move the splash screen for some apps.

Comment: Humm... so I think I have to resort to some sort of educated guess- like comparing the top-level windows before and after the file is opened to "guess" which window is the one. Still lossy, but can work in casual usages.

Comment: The main window may not be created until the user dismiss the login window. You got a heck load of education to do if you want to support every version of every software,

Comment: @ShengJiang蒋晟 My original intent was opening two documents side by side for easy comparison/reference, so MS Office, notepad, PDF reader, Browsers are the first targeted softwares.