# Open application or process from winform button resize it to specfic location

Tags: c#

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern  bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int x, int y, int width, int height, bool repaint);
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Process w = new Process();
     w.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("explorer.exe");
     w.Start();
     Thread.Sleep(5000);
     w.WaitForInputIdle();

     bool ok = MoveWindow(w.MainWindowHandle, 0, 0, 100, 50, true);
     if (!ok) throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception();
```

Comment: you can try this way : http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.setwindowpos

Comment: but......what is explorer's MainWindow?

Comment: my question is want to open any application or process through button which ever is selected will open to specific location on desktop

Comment: Dear sir Pranay Rana and   kennyzx please guide me i am new with c#  sir when should i use wpf or simple win form to make my appliation the code i used will work fine for notepad but not for other process

Comment: That is because not every process has a `MainWindowHandle`. I have asked [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14556479/815938) before, please refer to the comments to that question.

Comment: how i use enumwindow to resize process plz gudie sir

Comment: is any body there please gudie me